# Retornar dados de arquivo .lua no PHP em forma de array

Tags: php, json, array, lua

Preciso acessar alguns dados armazenados em um arquivo `.lua` no PHP.

Este é o conteúdo do arquivo `meu_arquivo.lua`:

```
tbl = {
    [22004] = {
        unidentifiedDisplayName = "Sapato",
        unidentifiedResourceName = "»÷µé",
        unidentifiedDescriptionName = {
            "Item não identificado. Pode ser identificado com uma [Lupa]."
        },
        identifiedDisplayName = "Botas Temporais DES",
        identifiedResourceName = "½Ã°£ÀÇ¼ÕÀçÁÖºÎÃ÷",
        identifiedDescriptionName = {
            "Botas incríveis que devem ter sido criadas há muito tempo, mas nunca foram usadas.",
            "^0000ffDEX +35.^000000",
            "Tipo: ^777777Calçado^000000",
            "Defesa: ^77777725^000000",
            "Peso: ^777777350^000000",
            "Nível necessário: ^77777799^000000",
            "Classes: ^777777Todas as classes^000000"
        },
        slotCount = 1,
        ClassNum = 0
    },
    [22005] = {
        unidentifiedDisplayName = "Sapato",
        unidentifiedResourceName = "»÷µé",
        unidentifiedDescriptionName = {
            "Item não identificado. Pode ser identificado com uma [Lupa]."
        },
        identifiedDisplayName = "Botas Temporais SOR",
        identifiedResourceName = "½Ã°£ÀÇÇà¿îºÎÃ÷",
        identifiedDescriptionName = {
            "Botas incríveis que devem ter sido criadas há muito tempo, mas nunca foram usadas.",
            "^0000ffLUK +35.^000000",
            "^0000ff+20 de Crítico.^000000",
            "Tipo: ^777777Calçado^000000",
            "Defesa: ^77777725^000000",
            "Peso: ^777777350^000000",
            "Nível necessário: ^77777799^000000",
            "Classes: ^777777Todas as classes^000000"
        },
        slotCount = 1,
        ClassNum = 0
    }
}
```

Exemplo: 
Quero retornar o valor de `tbl > 22004 > unidentifiedDisplayName` que seria `Sapato`como se fosse um vetor(array) própria do *PHP*:

`<?= $meu_arquivo['tbl']['22004']['unidentifiedDisplayName']; // mostra "Sapato" ?>`

Não conheço a sintaxe/linguagem desse arquivo pra apontar minha pesquisa com mais precisão. Minha única referência é que o arquivo é lido via *LUA* pela aplicação original (Jogo).

Por mais que tenha uma semelhança com o *JSON*, a função `json_decode` não funcionou para este arquivo.

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar a extensão Lua para PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.lua.php

Segue um exemplo utilizando seu arquivo `.lua` como input:

```
<?php
$lua = new Lua('./file.lua');
var_dump($lua->tbl[22004]['unidentifiedDisplayName']);
```

Produz o seguinte output:

```
string(6) "Sapato"
```

Vou deixar aqui também um exemplo de instalação da extensão lua no PHP (lógico que dependendo do seu ambiente de produção as instruções podem variar, mas como eu tive que rapidamente ter um ambiente para rodar a solução proposta, achei que poderia ser útil compartilhar)

```
FROM php:latest

RUN apt-get -y update \
 && apt-get -y install lua5.2 liblua5.2-0 liblua5.2-dev \
 && cp /usr/include/lua5.2/lua.h /usr/include/ \
 && ln -s /usr/include/lua*.*/ /usr/include/lua \
 && cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.a /usr/lib/liblua.a \
 && cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so /usr/lib/liblua.so \
 && pecl install lua-2.0.2 \
 && docker-php-ext-enable lua
```

Comment: Cara, funcionou legal! Única coisa que não gostei foi a necessidade de mexer nas extensões/componentes do PHP (PEAR/PECL). Vai dificultar um pouco pra hospedagem adicionar isso. Mas já valeu o joinha!

Comment: que bom que pude ajudar! talvez este composer package seja melhor pra vc então: https://github.com/koesie10/LuaSerializer
(A capacidade é limitada somente a serialização, mas pelo menos não precisa instalar nenhuma extensão)

Comment: Então, eu acabei criando uma classe utilizando regexp pra fazer o serviço que preciso. Ela não ficou genérica: é bem específica pra esse meu arquivo. Mas acabou dando tudo certo. Tá bem funcional. Mas de qualquer forma, esse package aí é 10 e totalmente dinâmico. Vou experimentar ele também!